# 2D Transformation, why does this behaviour occur

Tags: javascript, css, 2d, transform

I have the below code, in which i'm trying to animate the transformation of the blocks relative to an offset i've defined.
But instead of a smooth transformation i'm getting this really weird behaviour where it appears to be duplicating into triplets, then doubles, and then back to triplets and then back to single.

I know this is an optical illusion, but i'm curious why i'm not getting the expected behaviour of a gradual rotation around the defined point, but get this propellor effect.

I'm really new in 2d/3d manipulations, and I don't understand all the math of it, but I want to learn it, thats why i wrote this, to get a grasp of what actually happens with which numbers

I'm looking for an explanation why this behaviour occurs, because it's not really what I was expecting...

To recap: I am expecting a gradual rotation as the degrees increase, instead i'm getting this all over the place animation. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function BlockPos(x,y,z) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.z = z;
}
BlockPos.prototype.getX = function() {
  return this.x;
}
BlockPos.prototype.getZ = function() {
  return this.z;
}
BlockPos.prototype.getY = function() {
  return this.y;
}
BlockPos.prototype.setX = function(x) {
  this.x = x;
}
BlockPos.prototype.setZ = function(z) {
  this.z = z;
}
BlockPos.prototype.setY = function(y) {
  this.y = y;
}

function Block(color,blockpos) {
this.color = color;
this.blockpos = blockpos;
}
Block.prototype.getBlock = function() {
   return '<div style="display:inline-block;width:38px;height:38px;position:absolute;left:'+(this.blockpos.getX()*40)+'px;top:'+(this.blockpos.getZ()*40)+'px;border:1px solid gray;background-color:'+this.color+'"></div>';
}

arr = [
   new Block('green',new BlockPos(1,1,1)),
   new Block('green',new BlockPos(1,1,2)),
   new Block('green',new BlockPos(1,1,3)),
   new Block('red',new BlockPos(2,1,1)),
   new Block('red',new BlockPos(3,1,1)),
   new Block('red',new BlockPos(4,1,1)),
   new Block('red',new BlockPos(5,1,1))
];
html = '';
center = new BlockPos(0,1,0);
function rotateAroundPoint(pos, center,angle) {
//POINT rotate_point(float cx,float cy,float angle,POINT p)
  var s = Math.sin(angle);
  var c = Math.cos(angle);
  var p = new BlockPos(pos.getX(),pos.getY(),pos.getZ());
  // translate point back to origin:
  p.x -= center.getX();
  p.z -= center.getZ();

  // rotate point
  var xnew = p.x * c - p.z * s;
  var znew = p.x * s + p.z * c;

  // translate point back:
  p.x = xnew + center.getX();
  p.z = znew + center.getZ();
  return p;

}
function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
   return degrees * 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288 /180
}
function rotate(arr,center,degrees) {
    
     for(var c=0;c<arr.length;c++) {
         
         pos = rotateAroundPoint(arr[c].blockpos,center,degreesToRadians(degrees));
         

         arr[c].blockpos.setX(pos.getX());
         arr[c].blockpos.setZ(pos.getZ());

     }
     return arr;
}
var rotation = 0;
window.setInterval(function() {
  
  rotation+=1;
  if(rotation >= 360) rotation = 0;
  var html = rotation+' degrees<BR/>';
  arr = rotate(arr,center,rotation);
  for(c=0;c<arr.length;c++) {
     html += arr[c].getBlock();
  }
  $('#foo').html(html);
},50);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:relative;top:200px;left:200px;background-color:yellow;width:500px;height:500px;" id="foo">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core of the problem is here :

```
arr = rotate(arr,center,rotation);
```

You assign a rotation on an already rotated `arr` and don't take account of a *delta* time in your rotation function. Instead you rotate the (already rotated) `arr` by the total amount of time elapsed - which gives that acceleration/accumulation thing.

Consider the same code with a delta time of `1` instead.

```js
function BlockPos(x,y,z) {
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y;
   this.z = z;
}
BlockPos.prototype.getX = function() {
  return this.x;
}
BlockPos.prototype.getZ = function() {
  return this.z;
}
BlockPos.prototype.getY = function() {
  return this.y;
}
BlockPos.prototype.setX = function(x) {
  this.x = x;
}
BlockPos.prototype.setZ = function(z) {
  this.z = z;
}
BlockPos.prototype.setY = function(y) {
  this.y = y;
}

function Block(color,blockpos) {
this.color = color;
this.blockpos = blockpos;
}
Block.prototype.getBlock = function() {
   return '<div style="display:inline-block;width:38px;height:38px;position:absolute;left:'+(this.blockpos.getX()*40)+'px;top:'+(this.blockpos.getZ()*40)+'px;border:1px solid gray;background-color:'+this.color+'"></div>';
}

arr = [
   new Block('green',new BlockPos(1,1,1)),
   new Block('green',new BlockPos(1,1,2)),
   new Block('green',new BlockPos(1,1,3)),
   new Block('red',new BlockPos(2,1,1)),
   new Block('red',new BlockPos(3,1,1)),
   new Block('red',new BlockPos(4,1,1)),
   new Block('red',new BlockPos(5,1,1))
];
html = '';
center = new BlockPos(0,1,0);
function rotateAroundPoint(pos, center,angle) {
//POINT rotate_point(float cx,float cy,float angle,POINT p)
  var s = Math.sin(angle);
  var c = Math.cos(angle);
  var p = new BlockPos(pos.getX(),pos.getY(),pos.getZ());
  // translate point back to origin:
  p.x -= center.getX();
  p.z -= center.getZ();

  // rotate point
  var xnew = p.x * c - p.z * s;
  var znew = p.x * s + p.z * c;

  // translate point back:
  p.x = xnew + center.getX();
  p.z = znew + center.getZ();
  return p;

}
function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
   return degrees * 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288 /180
}
function rotate(arr,center,degrees) {
    
     for(var c=0;c<arr.length;c++) {
         
         pos = rotateAroundPoint(arr[c].blockpos,center,degreesToRadians(degrees));
         

         arr[c].blockpos.setX(pos.getX());
         arr[c].blockpos.setZ(pos.getZ());

     }
     return arr;
}
var rotation = 0;
window.setInterval(function() {
  
  rotation+=1;
  if(rotation >= 360) rotation = 0;
  var html = rotation+' degrees<BR/>';
  arr = rotate(arr,center,1);
  for(c=0;c<arr.length;c++) {
     html += arr[c].getBlock();
  }
  $('#foo').html(html);
},50);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position:relative;top:200px;left:200px;background-color:yellow;width:500px;height:500px;" id="foo">
</div>
```

Comment: ahhh, right, forgot about the overwriting the array part. Such a simple mistake. Thank you for this lesson :-)

Comment: Another way to look at it would be to start with a fresh (unmodified) array and using total time elapsed.

Comment: Yea, I gathered so much, to have a temp array drawn from the original object for drawing. `var tmpArr = rotate(arr,center,degrees);` is what I use now :-)

Answer (score -1):

Like you said it's an optical illusion, sort of. Since it's rotating so fast, the squares move a quarter or even a third of a rotation between each frame, so to your eyes, it looks like multiple copies of the object are present because it just "jumps" to its new location. there is nothing wrong with your code, it's just the way our eyes process movement. You can even see this in real life by just looking at a fan. At certain speeds, you see the blades moving slowly or even backward.

Comment: I know, but why isn't it gradually moving degree by degree, why is it jumping all over the place

Comment: @PinkTurtle I'm talking about what I've seen myself. it's not exactly the same, there is a blurred disc but you can "see" individual blades within it.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets It's because of the refresh rate of the browser (or screen, but that should be way above the browser's). You are moving it in small amount but by the time the browser redraws the frame, it has moved a quarter to a third of a rotation.